# Screen turns black after systemd message "Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch."

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and I've been having problems trying to boot. I'm in recovery mode right now.

My `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting is just `""`.

When I boot, the kernel boots normally, but then my screen turns black after systemd outputs this message.

`Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.`

How can I fix this?

EDIT 0: When I check display settings, Ubuntu says `Unknown Monitor`, 1024x768. My monitor is 1920x1080.

EDIT 1: My CPU and GPU:

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 2400GE w/ Radeon Vega Graphics (8) @ 3.200GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series
```

And my architecture is x86_64.

EDIT 2: I booted successfully! I just had to add `nomodeset`, but my display is still ruined (display settings say Unknown Monitor).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using a Dell Mini 1012, would you? 

Comment: My processor's an AMD Ryzen 5. It's a desktop, not a laptop.

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] your question to include a good deal more detail? Guessing about what sort of hardware you're using is not my idea of fun on a Sunday night ... and it ultimately wastes your time, too 

Comment: Should I send you neofetch output, @matigo?

Comment: Should I try booting with `nomodeset`?

Comment: I've added more details...